# Прервать закрытие вкладки JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Как отследить закрытие вкладки, так чтобы после события вывести свое сообщение?
Я нашел один из рабочих вариантов такой:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return "Данные не сохранены. Точно перейти?";
        };
```

только вот сообщение он не выводит.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Там, откуда Вы взяли этот пример, обработчик устанавливается кликом на кнопку. Чтобы установить его по умолчанию, можно воспользоваться двумя вариантами:

**1.** Объявить функцию и тут же вызвать её

```js
function setHandler() {
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Данные не сохранены. Точно перейти?";
  };
}

setHandler();
```

**2.** Self executing function

```js
(window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Данные не сохранены. Точно перейти?";
})();
```

Comment: почему то срабатывает раз через раз, а кастомное сообщение не работает, может есть еще какой нибудь вариант?

Comment: @Domilola: кастомное сообщение устанавливается вообще не так, как это показано в ответе (+ большинство браузеров его все равно не будет отображать), а так - других вариантов не имеется. Ибо это событие, вызывающееся непосредственно перед выгрузкой страницы